# How to properly exclude test files from tsdoc / typedoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, documentation-generation, typedoc, tsdoc

I am testing out some various documentation engines, and I'd like to try typedoc for our large project.  We have various test files (`somefile.test.ts` or `someotherfile.test.tsx`) throughout our project.  I'm struggling to get typedoc to ignore these files.  I did `npm i -D typedoc`, then in my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "configOptions": "some_options"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "typedocOptions": {
    "out": "docs",
    "entryPoints": "src/index.tsx",
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.test.ts*",
      "**/*.test.tsx*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I run my npm command `"tsdoc": "typedoc"` - `npm run tsdoc`.  Typedoc runs through my files and finds an absolute ton of typescript linting errors in my testing files, and so it fails to run.  (We recently updated our `@types/jest`, so eslint and ts are complaining about things like `Property 'toEqual' does not exist on type 'Assertion'` and `Property 'toMatchSnapshot' does not exist on type 'Assertion'`.  eslint and ts complain about these things, but it doesn't prevent the tests from running.  But what is wrong with my `typedocOptions` that it is not correctly ignoring these files?

Answer (score 0):

This is a total shot in the dark, but I'm going to guess that `typedoc` runs `tsc` before it attempts to generate the documentation, to create the linkages between files. It might not get to the point of checking which files to exclude if `tsc`/`eslint` are giving it errors.

I'd recommend looking into why the Jest upgrade is blowing things up. Once the compiler/linting errors are gone, I imagine `typedoc` will cooperate. You could also tell `tsc`/`eslint` to ignore those files, but I imagine that not compiling the test files will cause further problems down the line.

Comment: If that's the case, then the `exclude` property of `typedocOptions` seems kind of toothless to me.  In the end my team decided to go with handwritten docs using [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/), as typedoc seemed to be just a dressed up version of inline comments.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Well, it depends on what the authors of typedoc intended the exclusion for. My expectation would be that a docwriting app would use exclusions for files to not be documented, not files that shouldn't be compiled. A docwritsr would expect it was running on compilable code, just like javadoc.

Comment: I guess what's interesting is that even though my test files are full of typescript eslint problems since the @types/jest upgrade, they still compile and run fine through jest, but typedoc has a problem with it.  I may try out your suggestion to exlude all .test.ts files from eslint, because it doesn't seem anyone on the team cares that they have linting errors (we just focus on linting errors in the actual code, not the tests).  I'll see if I have time to try that out and I'll let you know if it helps.